# How to fix this instance of "can't find symbol"?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been given a driver which looks like the following:

```
public class LabTest_Driver
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] list = new int[20];
        System.out.println();
        makeList (list);
        System.out.print("\n" + "The original (unsorted) list is:" + "\n");
        showArray(list);
                .
                .
                .
    }
}
```

The makeList constructor is suppose to make an array of the length of list with 20 different non repeating numbers between 100 and 199(inclusive)

This is my class so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class LabTest
{
     private static int[] list;

public void makeList(int[] list)
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    this.list = list;
    int n = list.length;
    for (int element : list)
    {
        int w = ran.nextInt(100) + 99;
        list[element] = w;
        w = 0;
    }
}

public void showArray(int[] b)
{
    for (int element : list)
    {
        System.out.print(list[element] + " ");
    }
}
```

}

When I press compile it comes up with an error message saying "cannot find symbol - method makeList(int[])", but didn't I make that constructor correctly. If anyone could clarify this and help me with my programming problem that would be amazing.

Comment: I guess you need to make `makeList` as `static` and then call `LabTest.makeList(list);` instead of `makeList(list);`

Comment: Pretty sure you can't just use this.list = list, I think there is a copy method which you should use.

Comment: they're not even in the same class. either make it static and call it through the class, or through an instance of the class it's in.

Comment: @Stultuske And that accounts for the error.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi ... calling a (local) method that doesn't exist (locally), yes, that causes that error

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have two different classes for `Lab_Driver` and `LabTest`. You have to create a new Object of class `LabTest` and then invoke your methods i.e. `makeList()` and `showList()` on that Object. Alternatively, if the two methods are `static` you can call them directly by prefixing them with `LabTest`.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[] list = new int[20];
    System.out.println();
    LabTest labTest = new LabTest();
    labTest.makeList(list);
    System.out.print("\n" + "The original (unsorted) list is:" + "\n");
    labTest.showArray(list);
            .
            .
            .
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this if you make your methods `static`:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[] list = new int[20];
    System.out.println();
    LabTest.makeList(list);
    System.out.print("\n" + "The original (unsorted) list is:" + "\n");
    LabTest.showArray(list);
            .
            .
            .
}
```